# how to perform semi-supervised k-mean clustering

Tags: r, k-means

I am new in r. I am trying to perform semi-supervised k-means clustering. I plan to divide my 2/3 of my data as a training set, and 1/3 as a test set. My objective is to train a model using the known clusters, and then propagate the training model to the test set. the propagation result will be compare with the prior clusters. my objective is to check the prediction accuracy of kmeans clustering. Therefore I am wondering if there is a way we can do semi-supervised kmeans clustering using r? any package is needed. thank you.

thank you

regards,

Comment: What searching have you done?

Comment: may I know what do you mean by "what searching have you done?".

Comment: SO discourages requests for package recommendations and expects that you have put in effort at searching with facilities like Google and RSeek.org. Please review the material on SO Help pages: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching . They also ask that you be as specific as possible , so it is expected that you post a real problem with code and data.

Comment: If that is what you mean. Yes, I have searched it and have no luck on it. that is why I ask it here.

Comment: Improve your question along the lines I am outlining and people will be less likely to see it as low quality. At the moment is is not well defined and may be closed.

Comment: I am new in r. I am trying to perform semi-supervised k-means clustering. I plan to divide my 2/3 of my data as a training set, and 1/3 as a test set. My objective is to train a model using the known clusters, and then propagate the training model to the test set. the propagation result will be compare with the prior clusters. my objective is to check the prediction accuracy of kmeans clustering. Therefore I am wondering if there is a way we can do semi-supervised kmeans clustering using r? any package is needed. thank you.

Comment: You can use `ssc` package in r for semi-supervised classification.

Answer (score -2):

Use `kmeans()`. It should come with the `stats` package, which you should have if you've installed R correctly. You can read how to use functions by putting a `?` before the function call, e.g. `?kmeans()`.

Search online if you're still lost about how to use the function - there are plenty of guides and toy examples online.

M

Comment: Yes. you are right. I have managed to use means function in R for unsupervised clustering. My challenge here is about using means function for semi-supervised clustering. I have done searching without any result. thank you anyway.